# Getting last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I have an array which contains objects, these objects are in the same order and correspond to the `li`'s of a `ul`.

I was wondering if there was any negligible difference between doing:

(this.element is the `ul`'s)
`this.element.children(".tagit-choice:last").remove();`
vs
(this.tagsArray is the array of objects about the `li`'s)
`this.tagsArray[this.tagsArray.length -1].element.remove();`

or is there a better way (noting that when this is called tagsArray will always have something in it, so getting an index of -1 is not an issue)?

Comment: Those arrays looks weird, why aren't you using jQuery as normal?

Comment: This is part of a jQuery-ui plugin, basically we are maintaining an internal array of the tags, the array contains objects that contains information such as the tag value, label etc, it also contains element which is simply the jquery object that refers to the jQuery element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the more readable and maintable option:

```
.children(".tagit-choice:last").remove();
```